How do I capture the click event from Razor Component Library to my Maui Project?
I have all of my components in my shared RCL library.
I have a button in my Shared Component Libary Page
When I click this button I want to show a page that only exists in my MAUI project.
How do I do that?
<MudButton OnClick="@(NavigateToEdit(Profile.UserId))">
<MudText>Edit</MudText>
</MudButton>

Here is the method in my MAUI Project
<SharedPage/>

public void NavigateToEdit(string UserId)
{      
  MAUIProject () => MauiONLYPage(UserId)
}


You can use a DI service to define the configuration for each application.
public interface IUIConfigurationService<TRecord>
{
    public Type? EditForm {  get; set; }
    public string? EditFormUrl { get; set; }
}

Then in the Maui project you use this service:
public class MauiUIConfigurationService: IUIConfigurationService<WeaatherForcast>
{
    public Type EditForm { get; set; } = typeof(Home);
    public string? EditFormUrl { get; set; } = null;
}

And in the web project this:
public class WebUIConfigurationService : IUIConfigurationService<WeaatherForcast>
{
    public Type EditForm { get; set; } = null;
    public string? EditFormUrl { get; set; } = "/weatherforecast/Editor";
}

Your NavigateToEdit method then lives on the share library form and makes it's navigation decision based on the injected service.
